# Get state from display component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have one fetch and one display .js file. However I am trying to figure out how to read the state. Of course as it's done now it's returned from the other .js file. But I would like to use the state that was set instead. How would I refactor to do this?

I would like to use the stateURL prop in the DataLoader.js

DataLoader.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import useFetch from "./useFetch";

export default function DataLoader({stateURL}) {
  const data = useFetch("/api");

  // Should not be used
  console.log("data", data);
  const data2 = Object.keys(data).map(data => data);
  console.log("data2", data2);
  const data3 = data2.map(key => {
    console.log("inside data3", key );
    return data[key];
  });

  //This is empty
  console.log("state", stateURL);

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Testing</h1>
      <ul>
      {Object.keys(data3).map(key => {
        return <li>{data3[key].href}</li>;
      })} 
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

useFetch.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function useFetch(url) {
  const [stateURL, setStateURL] = useState([]);
  console.log("url", url);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setStateURL(data._links));
  }, []);
  console.log("stateURL", stateURL);
  return stateURL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. The hooks can only be referred from the original creating component.

Why do you just use the fetch hook within the display file?

If you want to keep these two components separated:

To access the data, you have to share the data somehow to be accessible to your other components. There are several ways to do it:

1. Pass the data up into the parent component via a callback and pass that into the other child component.
2. Using a state management library like Redux or Mobx.
3. Using the context API to share data between components but that might not be the best way for this kind of data.

It depends on your setup and your needs. If only these two components ever need that data, pushing it into the parent works fine.

If there are other components, which maybe need that data, you might want to use a state management lib.

Comment: Do you need that data somewhere else? Or just these 2 components?

Comment: This is just a lab app. It will contain many components that will share data in the future.

Comment: ok then you probably want to us a state management lib, sorry ;) It will save you a lot of headache in the long run.

Comment: Will do, but I see that there is a useReducer, so I guess this can go with Redux then.

Comment: That is not the redux hook but a different state hook. You need useSelector and useDispatch from redux itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198640/discussion-between-domino987-and-user2130951).